# Android animate Translate in android 2.2

Tags: android, animation, translate-animation

i have two image views which translates on click.
the animation works properly for one view but for second image view , my animation is not according to coordinates provided.

when i click top image view (img1) it animates properly toward bottom image view (img2) . But when i click the bottom image view, it animates from somewhere down and move towards image view 2 initial position only. though the expected behaviour is, it should animate from its position to top image view (img1) initial position.

My xml is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <ImageView  
        android:layout_width="100dp" 
        android:layout_height="100dp" 
        android:src="@drawable/letter_f"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/imgview1"
        android:background="@drawable/chart"/>

    <ImageView android:layout_height="100dp" 
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/imgview2" 
        android:src="@drawable/letter_g" 
        android:background="@drawable/chart" 
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and my java class file is

```
    public class AnimationDemo extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{   
    private ImageView img1;
    private ImageView img2;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        img1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgview1);
        img2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgview2);        
        img1.setOnClickListener(this);
        img2.setOnClickListener(this);
     }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) 
    {
        int x1,y1; // Coordinates of first image view
        int x2,y2; //Coordinates of second image view

        ImageView img = (ImageView)arg0;
        x1 = img1.getLeft();
        y1 = img1.getTop();

        x2 = img2.getLeft();
        y2 = img2.getTop();

        TranslateAnimation slide;
        if(arg0 == img1)
        {
            //translate from img view 1 to img view 2
            slide = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.ABSOLUTE,x1,Animation.ABSOLUTE, x2,Animation.ABSOLUTE, y1,Animation.ABSOLUTE,y2 );
        }
        else
        {
            // translate from img view 2 to img view 1
            slide = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.ABSOLUTE,x2,Animation.ABSOLUTE, x1,Animation.ABSOLUTE, y2,Animation.ABSOLUTE,y1);
        }
        slide.setDuration(1000);   
        slide.setFillAfter(true); 
        img.startAnimation(slide);
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to explain exactly what is going wrong instead of saying "not working". Is it animating to incorrect coordinates? at wrong duration? on the wrong touch?

Comment: when i click top image view (img1) it animates properly toward bottom image view (img2) . But when i click the bottom image view, it animates from somewhere down and move towards image view 2 initial position only.
though the expected behaviour is, it should animate from its position to top image view (img1) initial position.

Comment: I'm currently working on an issue of my own at the moment, when I get a chance I'll use your code and try to recreate and step through it. Possibly late, late tonight. Until then I'd look at your alignments on XML entities, and maybe step through your code in debugger and make sure your location values (x1, x2, y1, y3) are correct. I can't see anything that just jumps out at me though sorry.

Comment: I've outlined the answer below, would appreciate greatly marking as correct answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your troubles are due to your **locations**. I believe when animations are moved with absolute pixels it  is relative to itself. So on your second animation you were in essence moving it from x2=220 to x1=0, and y2=419 to y1=0. So it was moving from (currentX+220, currentY+419) to (currentX +0, currentY +0) which = itself

**To solve** this instance simply negate and switch the values of the second slide declaration like so:

```
TranslateAnimation slide;
        if(arg0 == img1)
        {
            //translate from img view 1 to img view 2
            slide = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.ABSOLUTE,x1,Animation.ABSOLUTE, x2,Animation.ABSOLUTE, y1,Animation.ABSOLUTE,y2 );
        }
        else
        {
            // translate from img view 2 to img view 1
//            slide = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.ABSOLUTE,x2,Animation.ABSOLUTE, x1,Animation.ABSOLUTE,y2,Animation.ABSOLUTE,y1);
            slide = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.ABSOLUTE,0,Animation.ABSOLUTE, (-x2),Animation.ABSOLUTE,0,Animation.ABSOLUTE, (-y2));
        }
```

**This only happens because your top left sprite is at 0,0 though**. You have to seriously rethink how you're moving your sprites around. Just remember, the TranslateAnimation moves them relative to their current positions, **basically setting the sprites original location to (0,0).**

Could be wrong, but hope it helps. It worked for me...

Sorry it took so long to get back to you, I lost your post and couldn't find it again for some reason. Glad you had commented earlier!